# install python huggingface datasets package without internet connection from python environment

Tags: python, package, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-datasets

I dont have access to internet connection from my python environment. I would like to install this [library](https://pypi.org/project/datasets/)

I also noticed this [page](https://pypi.org/project/datasets/#files) which has files required for the package. I installed that package by coping that file to my python environment and then running the below code

```
pip install 'datasets_package/datasets-1.18.3.tar.gz'
Successfully installed datasets-1.18.3 dill-0.3.4 fsspec-2022.1.0 multiprocess-0.70.12.2 pyarrow-6.0.1 xxhash-2.0.2
```

But when I try the below code

```
import datasets
datasets.load_dataset('imdb', split =['train', 'test'])
```

it throws error
`ConnectionError: Couldn't reach https://raw.githubusercontent.com/huggingface/datasets/1.18.3/datasets/imdb/imdb.py (error 403)`

I can access the file `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/huggingface/datasets/1.18.3/datasets/imdb/imdb.py` from outside my python enviroment

what files should I copy and what other code changes that I should make so that this line would work `datasets.load_dataset('imdb', split =['train', 'test'])` ?

#Update 1=====================

I followed below suggestions and copied below files within my python environment. So

```
os.listdir('huggingface_imdb_data/')
['dummy_data.zip',
 'dataset_infos.json',
 'imdb.py',
 'README.md',
 'aclImdb_v1.tar.gz']
```

The last file comes from `http://ai.stanford.edu/~amaas/data/sentiment/aclImdb_v1.tar.gz` and the other files come from `github.com/huggingface/datasets/tree/master/datasets/imdb`

Then I tried

```
import datasets
#datasets.load_dataset('imdb', split =['train', 'test'])
datasets.load_dataset('huggingface_imdb_data/aclImdb_v1.tar.gz')
```

but i get the below error :(

```
HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://huggingface.co/api/datasets/huggingface_imdb_data/aclImdb_v1.tar.gz?full=true
```

I also tried

```
datasets.load_from_disk('huggingface_imdb_data/aclImdb_v1.tar.gz')
```

but get the error

```
FileNotFoundError: Directory huggingface_imdb_data/aclImdb_v1.tar.gz is neither a dataset directory nor a dataset dict directory.
```

Comment: you shouldn't use the `load_from_disk` on the tar file, you mixed up the methods in my answer.

Comment: Also for offline usage: You should set this `export HF_DATASETS_OFFLINE=1` environment variable so the library wouldn't try to download anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the method 1 not working because not yet supported: https://github.com/huggingface/datasets/issues/761

> **Method 1.:**  You should use the `data_files` parameter of the
> `datasets.load_dataset` function, and provide the path to your local
> datafile. See the documentation:
> https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/package_reference/loading_methods.html#datasets.load_dataset
>
> ```
> datasets.load_dataset
> Parameters
> ...
> data_dir (str, optional) – Defining the data_dir of the dataset configuration.
> data_files (str or Sequence or Mapping, optional) – Path(s) to source data file(s).
> ...
> ```
>
> Update 1.: You should use something like this:
>
> ```
> datasets.load_dataset('imdb', split =['train', 'test'], data_files='huggingface_imdb_data/aclImdb_v1.tar.gz')
> ```

**Method 2.:**

Or check out this discussion: https://github.com/huggingface/datasets/issues/824#issuecomment-758358089

```
>here is my way to load a dataset offline, but it requires an online machine

(online machine)

    import datasets
    data = datasets.load_dataset(...)
    data.save_to_disk('./saved_imdb')

>copy the './saved_imdb' dir to the offline machine

(offline machine)

    import datasets
    data = datasets.load_from_disk('./saved_imdb')
```

Comment: Thanks. The first method seems applicable to me as I dont have access to internet from any of my python machines. My confusion is which file should i download from internet to load the `imdb` dataset. Could you point that file? thanks

Comment: In this file `https://github.com/huggingface/datasets/blob/master/datasets/imdb/imdb.py` there is a download URL probably that's  the one you want 
`_DOWNLOAD_URL = "http://ai.stanford.edu/~amaas/data/sentiment/aclImdb_v1.tar.gz"`

Comment: fyi - i went to https://github.com/huggingface/datasets/tree/master/datasets/imdb and downloaded all files and then tried `datasets.load_dataset('huggingface_imdb_data/dataset_infos.json')` but it gave error `HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://huggingface.co/api/datasets/huggingface_imdb_data/dataset_infos.json?full=true
` I will try your 2nd comment now

Comment: could you reply my update1? still having issues

Comment: I updated my answer (see Update 1), you should provide the `data_files` parameter alongside other othe ones  for the `load_dataset` function. Like this: `datasets.load_dataset('imdb', split =['train', 'test'], data_files='huggingface_imdb_data/aclImdb_v1.tar.gz')`

Comment: tried `abc=datasets.load_dataset('imdb', split =['train', 'test'], data_files='huggingface_imdb_data/aclImdb_v1.tar.gz')
` but still getting error `ConnectionError: Couldn't reach https://raw.githubusercontent.com/huggingface/datasets/1.18.3/datasets/imdb/imdb.py (error 403)
`

Comment: Okey, the first method not working because it's not supported... The second method should work. You should use an other machine with python to download  and save the data. Transfer directory to the machine you want to use the data and with the `load_from_disk` load in the directory. This should work